# Get Unzipped Folder Path - PHP

Tags: php, laravel, zip, unzip

How can i get the zipped file folder name after unzipping in php.

```
$zip = new \ZipArchive();

$zip->open(storage_path('app/'.$request->vrfile));

$zip->extractTo(public_path('tour_videos/videos/'.str_slug($company)));
$zip->close();

unlink(storage_path('app/'.$request->vrfile));
```

**Zipped file is called Kigali Home Web Tour**

[image]

**And After Unzipping the file the folder name is Web Tours**

[image]

**How can i get the folder name after extracting zipped files??**

Comment: Is `Web Tours` the company name or a name of a folder in the zip file?

Comment: create folder with name(you want).. copy zip file in that folder... go to that path unzip file

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = $zip->open(storage_path('app/'.$request->vrfile));
```

$name will give you an absolute path as well as the name of your folder.